# Barra superior, no consigo centrar css

Tags: html, css

estoy teniendo problemas con un ejercicio de la universidad.

Estoy intentando hacer una barra superior para mi página web:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero me queda así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si intento centrarlo usando widht no me queda igual ya que me ocupan una proporcion pero no dejando espacio en la izquierda y derecha.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo hacer para reducir el espacio de la derecha de cada uno?

os pongo mi css:

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;font-size:10;}

#navSup a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:inherit;
    font-size:14px;
} 

#navSup li{
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#000;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff;
    width: 20%; 
}


#navSup li:hover{
    background-color:#fff;
    color:#000;
}

#navSup li{
    float:left;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#000;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Indice página web</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Ejercicio PEC2 Lenguajes y estandares web" />
        <link href="css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>


    <body>

            

        <nav><ul id=navSup>
            <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Diseño Gráfico</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sobre mí</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Herramientas Color</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contactar</a></li>
            </ul></nav>
            

        <div class="container">

            <div class="container3">

                <!--Este es el contenedor con los elementos de sección, en donde debes incluir el texto que has de marcar   -->  
      

            </div>

        </div> 


        <div class="container2">
            <!-- Aquí introducimos el contenido principal de nuestra página -->
            <main>



            </main>

            <!-- aqui está nuestro pie de página -->

            <footer>

     

            </footer>
        </div>




    </body>
</html>
```

Necesito que quede como la primera imagen y no consigo que los espacios funcionen. Sé que me falta algo reelacionado con los margenes pero no acabo de conseguirlo... :(

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comentarios:

- Yo colocaría el menú `nav` dentro de una etiqueta mas (*por ejemplo un `section`*)

  - Lo anterior para que cuando le damos el ancho a este última (*al `section`*), podamos internamente re ajustar al contenedor de los elementos de navegación de manera independiente
- En lugar de usar un `inline-block` yo me apoyaría de *flexbox*

  - Para que con esto le podamos indicar al menú que en el eje horizontal mueva los elementos colocando un espacio al rededor de ellos
- Le damos un ancho menor del 100% al menú

  - El ancho menor del 100% en razón de la etiqueta donde incrustemos al menú
- Para poder centrar al menú nos apoyamos de un `margin: 0 auto;`

Con lo propuesta anterior se estará logrando:

- Tener al menú incrustado en otra etiqueta que de ancho ocupe el 100% del body
- Poder modificar el ancho del menú (*etiqueta `nav`* sin que esto comprometa el ancho de la etiqueta padre)

Propuesta:

```html
    <style>
      * {
        color: white;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .contenedor {
        background-color: black;
      }
      .contenedor-menu {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        width: 50%;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
      .contenedor-menu__elemento {
        list-style: none;
      }
    </style>
    <section class="contenedor">
      <nav class="contenedor-menu">
        <li class="contenedor-menu__elemento">
          1
        </li>
        <li class="contenedor-menu__elemento">
          2
        </li>
        <li class="contenedor-menu__elemento">
          3
        </li>
      </nav>
    </section>
```

**Referencias**

- [FlexBox](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)
- [justify-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content)

Answer (score 0):

Yo igual recomendaría usar flexbox en lugar de float, este último está quedando en desuso, aunque igual te funciona con float.

Yo limitaria el ancho de tu contenedor `UL` al deseado, colocaria un 100% al `nav`, lógicamente como estás flotando los `li`, no ocupan espacio en tu contenedor, por lo que `nav y ul` como tal, no se visualizan en el dom, esto lo puedes solucionar con un `overflow: hidden;`

Esta sería una salida rápida a tu proyecto, lógicamente tienes que prepararte para defender el proyecto, que es preferible, documentarse es lo mejor si quiere hacer las cosas bien.

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;font-size:10px;}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden; /*expando contenedor a alto del contenido flotante */
  background-color:#000;
}
#navSup {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px; /* limito el ancho de ul */
  margin: auto; /* centro ul */ 
}
#navSup a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:inherit;
    font-size:14px;
}

#navSup li{
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#000;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff;
    width: 20%; 
}

#navSup li:hover{
    background-color:#fff;
    color:#000;
}

#navSup li{
    float:left;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#000;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<nav><ul id=navSup>
            <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Diseño Gráfico</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sobre mí</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Herramientas Color</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contactar</a></li>
            </ul>
            </nav>
            

        <div class="container">

            <div class="container3">

                <!--Este es el contenedor con los elementos de sección, en donde debes incluir el texto que has de marcar   -->  
      

            </div>

        </div> 


        <div class="container2">
            <!-- Aquí introducimos el contenido principal de nuestra página -->
            <main>



            </main>

            <!-- aqui está nuestro pie de página -->

            <footer>

     

            </footer>
        </div>
```